# Earthquakes Gadget - update server location

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

I know that MS is not supporting the gadgets anymore.

Nevertheless I like those from http://addgadgets.com/ and have most of them in operation. 
Since a few weeks now the  Earthquakes Meter does not work anymore and report 'No Connection or Server Down'.

The message is clear. The server seems to have been shutdown or most probably updated.

Any idea on how to update the server location in the gadget, so that it can still be operational?

Comment: You'd have to know what it actually does. You might be able to snoop the connection using a packet sniffer and you could try to setup a hosts file entry to redirect it afterwards. But you'd have to have a server that actually delivers the correct data.